# Why the enteris of dictionay changes when I change a copy of values inside an iterator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have this dictionary,

```
dict = {'A':np.random.rand(2,2), 'B':np.random.rand(2,2)}
```

For some reasons, I need to to get a copy of items inside this dictionary and manipulate them as follows,

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    tmp = value
    tmp[1, 1] = 0
```

This actually changes the original values inside the dict! If I get a print, for example of the first entry,  I will see:

```
Initial value
[[0.46905019 0.5143053 ]
[0.9083885  0.62560836]]
Final Value
[[0.46905019 0.5143053 ]
[0.9083885  0.        ]]
```

So, how I can have a copy of dictionary items and manipulate them without changing the original values? Of course, one trivial solution is to make a copy of dictionary and work with the copy, but is there any other solution? And more importantly, is this behavior intentional or it is kind of unwanted?

Comment: You never call anything to make a copy of `value`. Probably look into `numpy.copy`

Comment: Making a shallow copy of the whole dictionary is not enough. You would need [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

Comment: `tmp` and `value` are refering to the same objects, as you can check by comparing `id(tmp)` and `id(value]` (python 3). For CPython the id is the address of the object in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [`.copy()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html) like this:

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    tmp = value.copy()
    tmp[1, 1] = 0
```